# Apply Udf on an array field(variable length) and split it into columns in pyspark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I want to apply a logic on an array field of **variable** length (0-4000) and split it into its columns. A udf with explode, creating new columns and renaming the columns will do the work, but I am not sure how to apply it iteratively as a udf. UDF will take the variable length array field and return the set of new columns (0-4000) to the dataframe. Sample input data frame shown below

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             hashval|    dec_spec (array|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|3c65252a67546832d...|[8.02337424829602...|
|f5448c29403c80ea7...|[7.50372884795069...|
|94ff32cd2cfab9919...|[5.85195317398756...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

output should look like

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
    |             hashval|    dec_spec (array|   ftr_1    |    ftr_2 | ftr_3 |...
    +--------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+--------+
    |3c65252a67546832d...|[8.02337424829602...|  8.023   | 3.21       | 4.23.....
    |f5448c29403c80ea7...|[7.50372884795069...| 7.502    | 8.23       |2.125
    |94ff32cd2cfab9919...|[5.85195317398756...|
    +--------------------+--------------------+
```

the udf can take some of the logic like this below

```
df_grp = df2.withColumn("explode_col", F.explode_outer("dec_spec"))
df_grp = df_grp.groupBy("hashval").pivot("explode_col").agg(F.avg("explode_col"))
```

below for renaming columns

```
count = 1
for col in df_grp.columns:
  if col != "hashval":
    df_grp = df_grp.withColumnRenamed(col, "ftr"+str(count))
    count = count+1
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS For the code above, have taken help from others in the forum here.

Comment: your column dec_spec is varying length? but want to explode to 4000 columns?

Comment: array is varying length. so if there are only 20 elements for a particular row, then it will be 20 columns. Array field in some rows can have 2048 elements, then there will be 2048 columns. but maximum i need to handle is to 4000. anything above that, i can throw it away

Comment: so the rest of columns will be null right?

Comment: yes; if there r only 20 elements in the first row and second row array field has 40 elements, then for the first row, after 20th column wil be null
table field will contain arrays of varied lengths with the max of 4000.i can throw away after that.

Comment: see answer, in my case, i use 3 as my input length, kindly change to 4000 and apply to your problem

Answer (score 0):

mock sample data

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField, StringType
sdf1 = sc.parallelize([["aaa", "1,2,3"],["bbb", "1,2,3,4,5"]]).toDF(["hash_val", "arr_str"])
sdf2 = sdf1.withColumn("arr", sf.split("arr_str", ","))
sdf2.show()

+--------+---------+---------------+
|hash_val|  arr_str|            arr|
+--------+---------+---------------+
|     aaa|    1,2,3|      [1, 2, 3]|
|     bbb|1,2,3,4,5|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+--------+---------+---------------+
```

udf to make all array same length

```
schema = ArrayType(StringType())

def fill_list(input_list, input_length):
    fill_len = input_length - len(input_list)
    if fill_len > 0:
        input_list += [None]*(fill_len)
    
    return input_list[0:input_length]

fill_list_udf = udf(fill_list, schema)
sdf3 = sdf2.withColumn("arr1", fill_list_udf(sf.col("arr"), sf.lit(3)))
sdf3.show()

+--------+---------+---------------+---------+
|hash_val|  arr_str|            arr|     arr1|
+--------+---------+---------------+---------+
|     aaa|    1,2,3|      [1, 2, 3]|[1, 2, 3]|
|     bbb|1,2,3,4,5|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|[1, 2, 3]|
+--------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

expand them

```
sdf3.select("hash_val", *[sf.col("arr1")[i] for i in range(3)]).show()
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|hash_val|arr1[0]|arr1[1]|arr1[2]|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|     aaa|      1|      2|      3|
|     bbb|      1|      2|      3|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting some errors when the index grows high.
wondering what does this do
  if fill_len > 0:
        input_list += [None]*(fill_len)
initutively, i understand it fills up the end portion after the specified length.

Comment: Getting error for when the length gets to 90 or so.
An error occurred while calling o19712.showString.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 753.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 753.0 (TID 6414, hpcb08r05d02.hpc.ford.com, executor 174): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1220, Column 14: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1220, Column 14: Expression "isNull_6" is not an rvalue

Comment: right , it expand the list that is lower than 90 to be up to 90 length

Comment: i changed the data to a bigger value, still works for my example, i wonder any data difference in your enviroment

Comment: Yes true. Some data issue possibly.